# Need to restrict acceptable input box values (and length of text) using js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Got the following code to restrict input box entry to just numbers (no alphabets, no special characters) and limit input to 3 characters for the first two boxes and 4 for the third box.  But I'm unable to prevent user from entering special characters (those that user presses Shift+number to obtain), nor am I able to limit the number of characters per box to 3, 3 and 4, respectively.  What is my code missing?  Also, the behavior of these text boxes in Chrome is especially odd - Chrome doesn't even let me enter any value in any of the input boxes.  I'd also like to allow for the possibility of using Ctrl-c, Ctrl-x and Ctrl-v (to copy, cut and paste data) in these boxes, but can't figure out how to implement them.  For what it's worth, I've looked through several suggestions on this topic but can't fix my code still.

Code from rvPhoneInput.js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('rvComponents')
    .component('rvPhoneInput', {
      bindings: {
        compare: '=?',
        form: '<',
        inline: '<?',
        isRequired: '<?',
        label: '@?',
        name: '@',
        nextElem: '@?',
        value: '=',
        isDisabled: '<?'
      },
      controller: PhoneInputController,
      require: {
        modelCtrl: 'ngModel',
        modelOptsCtrl: 'ngModelOptions'
      },
      templateUrl: './components/rvPhoneInput/rvPhoneInput.html'
    });

  function PhoneInputController($element, $scope, $window) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.phone = [
      {
        name: ctrl.name + 1,
        num: ''
      },
      {
        name: ctrl.name + 2,
        num: ''
      },
      {
        name: ctrl.name + 3,
        num: ''
      }
    ];

    ctrl.modelOpts = {
      allowInvalid: true
    };
    $element.attr('ng-model-options', JSON.stringify(ctrl.modelOpts));

    $scope.$watch('$ctrl.value', function(newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        if (newVal.length === 10) {
          ctrl.phone[0].num = newVal.substring(0, 3);
          ctrl.phone[1].num = newVal.substring(3, 6);
          ctrl.phone[2].num = newVal.substring(6, 10);
        }
      } else {
        ctrl.phone[0].num = ctrl.phone[1].num = ctrl.phone[2].num = '';
      }
    });

    $scope.$watchGroup(['$ctrl.phone[0].num', '$ctrl.phone[1].num', '$ctrl.phone[2].num'], function(newVals) {
      var newPhoneNum = (newVals[0] || '') + (newVals[1] || '') + (newVals[2] || '');
      if (newPhoneNum) {
        if (ctrl.value !== newPhoneNum) {
          ctrl.value = newPhoneNum;
          ctrl.modelCtrl && ctrl.modelCtrl.$setViewValue(newPhoneNum);
        }
      } else {
        ctrl.value = undefined;
      }
    });

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      if (ctrl.modelCtrl) {
        ctrl.modelCtrl.$validators.sameNum = function(modelVal) {
          return !modelVal || !ctrl.compare || (modelVal && modelVal !== ctrl.compare);
        };
        ctrl.modelCtrl.$validators.phoneLength = function(modelVal) {
          return !modelVal || (modelVal && modelVal.length === 10);
        };
      }
      if (ctrl.modelOptsCtrl) {
        angular.merge(ctrl.modelOptsCtrl.$options, ctrl.modelOpts);
      }
    };

    $element.on('phoneFocus', function(evt) {
      $element.find('input[name="'+ctrl.phone[0].name+'"]').focus();
    });

    ctrl.maxlength = maxlength;
    ctrl.validateRequired = validateRequired;

    function maxlength(e, max, pos) {
      if (e.which === 9 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 16) {
        return true;
      }

      var isBackspace = e.which === 8;
      var isLeftArrow = e.which === 37;
      var isRightArrow = e.which === 39;          

      if (!isBackspace && !isLeftArrow && !isRightArrow && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return e.preventDefault();
      }

      var inputLength = (ctrl.phone[pos].num || '').length;
      if (inputLength === max - 1 || ((inputLength === 1 || !inputLength) && isBackspace)) {
        var watcher = $scope.$watch(function() {
          return (ctrl.phone[pos].num || '').length;
        }, function(newVal) {
          // focus to next element when input's pre-determined length is reached
          if (newVal === (pos === 2 ? 4 : 3) || !newVal) {
            var elem;
            if (!newVal) {
              elem = $element.find('input[name="'+ctrl.phone[pos === 0 ? pos : pos-1].name+'"]');
            } else {
              elem = (pos === 2) ? $(ctrl.nextElem) : $element.find('input[name="'+ctrl.phone[pos+1].name+'"]');
            }
            elem.focus();

            // destroy watch
            watcher();
          }
        });
      } else if (inputLength >= max && !isBackspace && !isLeftArrow && !isRightArrow) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    function validateRequired() {
      return ctrl.form.$submitted && ctrl.phone.every(function(phone) {
        return ctrl.form[phone.name].$error.required;
      }) && !ctrl.isDisabled;
    }
  }

  PhoneInputController.$inject = ['$element', '$scope', '$window'];
})(angular);
```

and here's the code from my html file (rvPhoneInput.html):

```
<div ng-class="$ctrl.inline ? 'form-inline' : 'form-group'">
  <label ng-if="$ctrl.label">{{$ctrl.label}}<span style="color:red;" ng-if="$ctrl.isRequired">*</span></label>
  <div ng-class="$ctrl.inline ? 'd-inline-block' : ''">
    <span class="color-black">(</span>
    <input type="text" name="{{$ctrl.phone[0].name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.phone[0].num" ng-required="$ctrl.isRequired"
      ng-minlength="3" ng-model-options="$ctrl.modelOpts" ng-keydown="$ctrl.maxlength($event, 3, 0)" ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled">
    <span class="color-black">)</span>
    <input type="text" name="{{$ctrl.phone[1].name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.phone[1].num" ng-required="$ctrl.isRequired" ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled"
      ng-minlength="3" ng-model-options="$ctrl.modelOpts" ng-keydown="$ctrl.maxlength($event, 3, 1)">
    <span class="color-black">-</span>
    <input type="text" name="{{$ctrl.phone[2].name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.phone[2].num" ng-required="$ctrl.isRequired" ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled"
      ng-minlength="4" ng-model-options="$ctrl.modelOpts" ng-keydown="$ctrl.maxlength($event, 4, 2)">
  </div>
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.validateRequired()" class="error-label">
    <div class="text-danger">This is a required field.</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="$ctrl.form.$submitted && $ctrl.form[$ctrl.name].$error" class="error-label">
    <div class="text-danger" ng-message="sameNum">Your <span style="text-transform: lowercase">{{$ctrl.label}}</span> cannot be the same as your cell number.</div>
    <div class="text-danger" ng-message="phoneLength">Phone number must be 10 digits.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My first thought is - why don't you use `<input type="number" min="0" max="999">` (see the first demo at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: Already tried.  But some browsers don't restrict input to just numbers when using <input type = "number">.

Comment: BTW, does anybody know why I'm unable to select text in the phone number fields and overwrite them with new text as opposed to having to backspace them and then write new text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the *Angular* way of doing things (I use "Vue"), but this snippet will allow only numbers, parentheses, space, and dash to be typed into the field.  You could do *just numbers* if you wanted, using `var regx = /\d/;`

First, I use the `type="tel"` — it doesn't help you for the input restriction or validation, but it *does* hint to mobile devices that they could put up a custom keyboard optimized for phone input.

```js
var regx = /[0-9 ()-]/;
var inp = document.getElementById('field1');

inp.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log('key: ' + e.key);
    if (! e.key.match(regx)) {
        // if the key doesn't match the allowed characters,
        // prevent it from being entered.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <label for="field1">Phone:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="field1" name="stuff" placeholder="Enter Phone" />
</form>
```

This restriction guarantees only the allowed characters are typed, but still needs validation — for example, this would allow you to type `7)-3    82(-)` which contains only the allowed characters, but is obviously not valid.

You could use html5 [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression) validation, but you might end up being too restrictive... for example, when I accept a phone input I allow a variety of formats: `(nnn) nnn-nnnn`, `nnnnnnnnnn`, `nnn-nnn-nnnn`, `nnn.nnn.nnnn` (and that doesn't even account for international phone numbers)

Don't forget to validate both in JS on the client and also validate on the server.

For more on the "tel" input type, see [the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel), especially the *[Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#Validation)* section.

Of course, someone may have already written an Angular widget for phone numbers so you wouldn't have to write this yourself.